# Given $x,y > 0$ and $x^n < y$ where $n\in \Bbb N$. Without using the existence of $y^{1/n}$, show that $\exists z$ s.t. $z > x$ and $z^n < y$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $y > 0$, $x > 0$ and $x^n < y$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Without using the existence of the $n$th root of $y$, show that there exists $z$, such that $z > x$ and $z^n < y$.

It is given that $x,y \in 
\mathbb R$.

The book's hint states that: "You can let $z = x + ε$. The binomial theorem may be useful."

This is what I have tried by myself. I have let $z=x+h$ and thus: $$z^n=(x+h)^n=x^n+nhx^{n-1} + \cdots +h^n > x^n+hnx^{n-1}<y$$ but I don't know how to choose a suitable $h$ from here.

In the section where this problem appears, we have defined the construction of the real numbers and their axioms. I have studied Dedekind cuts, least and upper bounds, and the formal definition of supremum, but I have not studied limits yet.

Comment: Can you check that the LaTeX formatting edit corresponds to your problem ?

Comment: it is not my hint it is the hint which suggested by the book wich i am reading

Comment: For getting a "full solution" you need to show your "partial solution".(i.e. what you have tried so far)

Comment: let z=x+h and z^n=(x+h)^n=x^n+n*h*x^(n-1)...h^n > x^n+h*n*x^(n-1)<y but i dont now how define h frome here

Comment: Have you studied supremum, infimum, maximum, minimum and stuff? What about limits?

Comment: i have studied dedikend section least and upper bound sup axiom but not limit yet

Comment: Ok..so in this problem is it given $\;x,y\in\Bbb Q\;$ ?

Comment: we defined real numbers and its axioms so x,y in R

Comment: @emilagazade If you bear with us, and give us the information that will improve the question, your question will be reopened even after it has been closed. At the moment, there are 4 reopen votes on your question, and after the 5th vote has been cast, your question will be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = x+h$ where $h>0$ but we can muck with it to make it small.

$z^n = (x+h)^n = x^n + c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + ..... + h^n$. For some $c_k = {n\choose k}$.

Now we *want* $ x^n + c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + ..... + h^n <y $ so we *want* $ 0< c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + ..... + h^n < y-x^n$

Can we do that?

We can pick $h$ so that $h< 1$.  That will mean $h >h^2 > h^3 >....$ and so $c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + .... + h^2 < c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h + .... + h$.

Now if we can pick an $h$ so that $c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h + .... + h=h(c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1)\le y-x^n$ that would mean $c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + .... + h^2 < c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h + .... + h=h(c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1)\le y-x^n$  That would be *more* than we need but it will definitely be enough.

So we *want* $0< h< 1$ and $h(c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1)\le y-x^n$.

Can we do that?

But notice $c_k > 0$ and $x^k > 0$ and so $c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1 > 0$.

So we set $c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1 = K$  we have $K >0$.

And we *want* $0< h < 1$ and $hK <  y-x^n$.

Can we do that?

If $hK < \frac y-x^n$ and $K > 0$  then $h < \frac {y-x^n}K$.

So we *want* $0< h< 1$ and $h<\frac {y-x^n}K$.

Can we do that?

Of course we can!  Just pick any $h$ so that $0< h < \min(1,\frac {y-x^n}K)$.

(for example:  Let $h = 0.99\min(1,\frac {y-x^n}K)$.  But surely we are beyond the point of having to *find* the $h$.  Surely we know we can find real numbers between $0$ and $\min(1,\frac {y-x^n}K)$.)

Then if $z = x+h$ we have

$z^n = (x+h)^n = x^n + c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h^2 + ..... + h^n < $

$x^n + c_1x^{n-1}h + c_2x^{n-2}h + ..... + h=$

$x^n + h(c_1x^{n-1} + c_2x^{x-2} + ..... + 1) =$

$x^n + hK < $

$x^n + \frac {y-x^n}K K =$

$x^n +(y-x^n) = y$.

And that's it.  We found our $z$.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir at last the anwer satisfied me. again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use Bernoulli's inequality
$$ (1+x)^n\ge 1+nx\qquad\text{for }x\ge-1,n\in\Bbb N.$$
From this,
$$ \left(\frac1{1-\epsilon}\right)^n\le\frac1{1-n\epsilon}\qquad\text{for }n\in\Bbb N, 0<\epsilon<\frac1n.$$
This will allow us to take $z=\frac x{1-\epsilon}$ as it suffices to achieve  $\frac{x^n}{1-n\epsilon}<y$. We do so by taking
$$ 0<\epsilon<\frac{1-\frac{x^n}{y}}n.$$